# Как очистить ввод телефона от символов js?

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь удалить всё при вводе телефона, кроме + в начале

```
$('.text').keyup(function(){  
 var tVal=($(".text").val().replace(/[^\+{0,1}0-9]/g, '')); 
$(".text").val(tVal); 
});
```

Подскажите почему в этом примере допускается несколько + и как исправить что бы он был только в начале строки

```
898+5565++
+898+556
```

Comment: паттерн инпуту лучше задайте

Comment: https://webshake.ru/php-dlya-professionalov/regulyarki-v-php вот отличная статья по регулярным выражениям,  а тут https://regex101.com можно их практиковать, советую вам немного сменить реализацию данного примера, намучаетесь. Опиши подробнее почему именно такая механика и  как все должно работать в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, где-то есть более красивое решение для сего.

Первое, лучше не на keyup, а на input.
Второе, вы можете удалять все плюсы, а потом просто добавить в начало - зачем усложнять, когда всё просто